# Plot a histogram where the bars are coloured based on a second list of values

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I can plot a histogram in Python for example with matplotlib:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
x = [3,5,12,7,8,6,4,6]
plt.hist(x)
```

However I have a second array `y = [4,6,8,2,4,5,8,7]` where each value corresponds to the value at the same position of `x`. Now I would like to create a histogram where each bar's height is defined by `x`, but each bar's color is defined by the values in `y` that belong to its `x` values. You could also say I have tuples as in `list(zip(x,y))` where the first value should be used for the histogram itself and the mean value of the second tuple value in each bin should determine the color.

Comment: If you use `plt.hist(x)` you are not plotting _"a histogram where each bar's height is defined by the values in `x`"_

Comment: @gboffi I edited the sentence to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`np.unique(x, return_counts=True)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) returns an array with the unique values of `x` and their count.

Converting everything to numpy arrays, `y[x == val]` selects the subset of `y` at each position where `x` is equal to `val`.  `y[x == val].mean()` gets the mean of those values.  Calling `cmap(norm(...))` gives the color corresponding to that value. The `cmap` and `norm` can be used to create a colorbar.

Here is some example code, including embellishments to change ticks, margins and spines:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable
import numpy as np

x = np.array([3, 5, 12, 7, 8, 6, 4, 6])
y = np.array([4, 6, 8, 2, 4, 5, 8, 7])

values, counts = np.unique(x, return_counts=True)
cmap = plt.get_cmap('inferno')
norm = plt.Normalize(0, y.max())  # or plt.Normalize(y.min(), y.max())
colors = [cmap(norm(y[x == val].mean())) for val in values]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(values, counts, color=colors, edgecolor='black')
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
ax.set_ylabel('Count')
ax.margins(x=0.02, y=0)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
plt.colorbar(ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm), pad=0.02, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

[image: histogram with colors from other array]

Here is another example, using the `tips` dataset from seaborn, with the rounded total_bill on the x-axis, the count on the y-axis and colored via the tip amount.

```py
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
x = np.round(tips['total_bill'])
y = np.array(tips['tip'])

values, counts = np.unique(x, return_counts=True)
cmap = plt.get_cmap('turbo')
```

[image: histogram with total_amount on x colored by tip]

PS: As mentioned in @Arne's answer, seaborn can be used to replace the norm and color assignment with seaborn's `hue`. Without embelishments, the code would look like:

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

x = np.array([3, 5, 12, 7, 8, 6, 4, 6])
y = np.array([4, 6, 8, 2, 4, 5, 8, 7])

values, counts = np.unique(x, return_counts=True)
sns.set_style('darkgrid')
ax = sns.barplot(x=values, y=counts, hue=[y[x == val].mean() for val in values],
                 palette='inferno', dodge=False)
```

[image: seaborn barplot]

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for the pyplot solution. I added binning using `np.array_split()` on the counts and values and then taking the mean of each values-bin as bar location and the sum of each counts-bin as bar height.

Answer (score 1):

The [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/) library is very useful to visualize multi-dimensional data like these. You could store `x` and `y` in a pandas dataframe and then add the bin numbers and the average `y` values per bin:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

x = [3, 5, 12, 7, 8, 6, 4, 6]
y = [4, 6, 8, 2, 4, 5, 8, 7]
n_bins = 4  # number of bins for the histogram

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y})

_, bin_edges = np.histogram(x, bins=n_bins)
df['bin'] = pd.cut(x, bins=bin_edges, labels=False, include_lowest=True)

color = df.groupby('bin').mean()['y']
df['color'] = df.bin.apply(lambda k: color[k])

df
```

```
    x   y   bin  color
0   3   4   0    6.000000
1   5   6   0    6.000000
2   12  8   3    8.000000
3   7   2   1    4.666667
4   8   4   2    4.000000
5   6   5   1    4.666667
6   4   8   0    6.000000
7   6   7   1    4.666667
```

Then drawing the colored histogram is easy:

```py
sns.histplot(data=df, x='x', bins=bin_edges, hue='color');
```

[image: colored histogram]